# Help me to get the result based on condition

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-data

I have created a Users class based on NSManagedObject with following attributes (id,name,age etc).

I am using the core data model but i am not sure how to do the follwing...

Now i would like to know How can i get the user detail based on user id.

example: `select * from users where id = 1`

please help me out.

Comment: A word of warning: Core Data is not SQL. Entities are not tables. Objects are not rows. Attributes are not columns. Relationships are not joins. Core Data is an object graph management system that may or may not persist the object graph and may or may not use SQL far behind the scenes to do so. Trying to think of Core Data in SQL terms will cause you to completely misunderstand Core Data and result in much grief and wasted time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **`NSPredicate`** class for executing SQL commands. The code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext; // specify your MOC object

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"users" inManagedObjectContext:context]; // specify your entity (table)
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicatewithFormat:@"id == %d",yourID]; // specify your condition (predicate)

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]; // execute

[entity release];
[predicate release];
[fetchRequest release];

if (array == nil) {
    // Error: no objects returned
} else {
    // Success: do whatever you want
}
```

---

### Step 1: Alloc/init NSFetchRequest

You need to alloc/init a NSFetchRequest object if you want to execute queries.

### Step 2: Select entity

If you want to specify `select * from users ...`, you should use `NSEntityDescription`:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"users" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

At the end you need to 'attach' your entity description to your NSFetchRequest object via:

```
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

### Step 3: Condition

If you want to have a condition (e.g. `... where id = 1`), you have to implement `NSPredicate`.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicatewithFormat:@"id == %d",yourID];
```

`yourID` must be a number (e.g. `1`, `2`, `7` or `46`).

And, again:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

### Step 4: Let's execute it!

```
NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

All the records that meet the conditions will be returned as array of NSManagedObjects.

### Step 5: Release objects

```
[entity release];
[predicate release];
[fetchRequest release];
```

### Step 6: Do something

If there are no objects that meet the conditions, `array` object will be `nil`. You can check it and deal with the error via:

```
if (array == nil)
```

---

Check out [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) for more info. :)

Comment: +1 A quibble: NSPredicate does not execute SQL commands. Core Data is not a SQL wrapper. SQL is just one of many persistence options and NSPredicate works with them all. At best, NSPredicate is ***analogous*** to the `WHERE` SQL statement. It is the NSFetchRequest that is ***analogous*** to an actual SQL statement.